# Difference between 64 bit.rpm and 64 bit.deb packages

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deb, rpm, alien

What is the difference between software installation files called **64 bit.deb** and **64 bit.rpm**?

I want to understand which one is best for my computer so that I am downloading and installing the correct one.

Comment: RPM is not for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

#### Summary:

If you use Ubuntu, always go for `.deb` packages!

They can be installed with the terminal command below:

```
sudo dpkg -i /PATH/TO/PACKAGE-FILE.deb
```

Or by simply double-clicking on them in your Files Manager, which opens them in the Software Center application.

#### Explanation:

There is a set of "basic Linux distributions" on which most others are based on. Two of the most important ones are probably **Debian** and **Red Hat**.
Ubuntu and all of its derivates are based on Debian.

Now those two Linux distributions have different software packaging systems:

- Debian uses `.deb` packages (simply derived from the first 3 letters of "Debian")
- Red Hat uses `.rpm` packages (**R**ed Hat **P**ackage **M**anager)

Those two packaging systems have some differences and are not compatible, that means you can't natively install RPM packages on a Debian-based system like Ubuntu.

**However**, in some cases you will be able to convert packages from one systems into another using the command-line tool `alien`.

Comment: Perfect answer, i got.